# What does SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED mean in Facebook SDK 3.0.1b for Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on an app and it has code in which I have extended my class with `FacebookActivity` and I wanted to know what does OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED mean and when will this portion execute

```
if (state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) { 
                        //WHEN THIS PORTION WILL EXECUTE
                    }
```

Facebook documents are not so good. See below code also

```
    @Override
    protected void onSessionStateChange(SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (isResumed) { //if its a visible activity
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount(); //get number of entries currently in the back-stack
            for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
                manager.popBackStack(); //clear fragment back-stack before new fragment is added
            }
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                if (state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) { 
                    //WHEN THIS PORTION WILL EXECUTE
                }else{
                    //replace fragment on main with promo fragment
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.body_frame, fragments[NextFgragment]).commit();

                }
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {

                //replace fragment on main with login fragment
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initially open a session, it will be in the SessionState.OPENED state. If you make a reauthorize request, or if the token gets refreshed, then it will be in an OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED state.

Generally you can treat both OPENED and OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED as the same, but sometimes (like if you request more permissions), you'll want to know when the token has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can just disable this code

```
if (state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) { 
                    //WHEN THIS PORTION WILL EXECUTE
                }
```

Comment: But what is the purpose of this part of code, little explication will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation the SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED say:

"Indicates that the Session is opened and that the token has changed. In this state, the Session may be used with Request."

that portion of code is useful, if need do something when the token change